# Views to display nodes based on ACL permission

Tags: 7, views, users

I'm trying to use Flexiaccess with ACL to build a view based on node that the user has access granted by Flexiaccess.

I found this on Drupal.org, it's the same use case, but is not working for me maybe because is for Drupal 6. (http://drupal.org/node/549412):

> > Here's how to do it:
>
> Under Arguments, create a new argument: "Node: Nid"
>
> Under "Action to take if argument is not present", select "Provide
>   default argument"
>
> Set the "Default argument type" to "PHP Code", and enter the
>   following:
>
> global $user; return db_result(db_query("SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(an.nid AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ',') FROM {acl_user} au
>   INNER JOIN {acl_node} an ON au.acl_id = an.acl_id WHERE an.grant_view
>   = 1 AND au.uid = %d", $user->uid));
>
> Then check "Allow multiple terms per argument", and click "Update".

I follow those steps but my view shows nothing.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://www.drupal.org/node/1255426, Drupal 7 does not have db_result function. You have to replace it with db_query().

Code which worked in my special case:

```
<?php
global $user;
$query = db_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(an.nid AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ',') FROM {acl_user} au INNER JOIN {acl_node} an ON au.acl_id = an.acl_id WHERE an.grant_view = 1 AND au.uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $user->uid));
$result = $query->fetchObject();
return reset($result);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Contextual Filters instead of arguments in Drupal 7 and check "Provide default value" and in PHP code insert like this.

```
global $user; 
$query = db_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(an.nid AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ',') FROM {acl_user} au INNER JOIN {acl_node} an ON au.acl_id = an.acl_id WHERE an.grant_view = 1 AND au.uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $user->uid));

$result = $query->fetchObject();
 return reset($result);
```

You can also get users allowed to view against each node like this by adding field for "views PHP" with this code

```
$query = db_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(au.uid AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ',') FROM acl_user as au INNER JOIN acl_node as an ON au.acl_id = an.acl_id WHERE an.grant_view = 1 AND an.nid =$row->nid ");
$result = $query->fetchObject();
$res = reset($result);

$myArray = explode(',', $res);
//print_r($myArray);
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
                     $user_id = $value;
                     $query_user = db_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid = $user_id");
                    $result_u = $query_user->fetchObject();
                    print "<span>" .$result_u->name. "  </span>";

          }
```