# Flexi access : create a view of content allowed

Tags: views, nodes, users, emails

I'm using Flexi Access in my project to allowed some users to see nodes with the ACL. But can we use Views with flexi access to create a view who regroup all nodes allowed to this user ?

If we can't, there is a solution to show the nodes allowed on normal view ? For example : The users with role 'admin' and 'project' can see every node of entity contact in view 'contact_view' because they have access to entity contact. And my role 'External' can just see the contacts allowed to him in this view but he doesn't access to entity contact.

Edit : Example with image

Here my view saw by role 'admin' and 'Project'
[image]

Here the same view saw by role 'external' : Nothing because he hasn't access to the entity shown in this view, but he has acces to the view.

[image]

I allowed my user with flexi access to see the node with id : 6166. In my view, i just want to see the row with line 6166 like this :
[image]

I hope you understand.

Thanks

Comment: I must admit I don't quite understand what are you tryingo to ask. Sorry.

Comment: i tried to rewrite my request, but i just want to create a view with content allowed to me by ACL.

Comment: Any properly implemented access control will filter all views, unless you specifically tell views *not to* allow this, so I fail to see your problem. Make default view. If you see nodes not allowed, file a bug report to ACL module. should be that simple.

Comment: I updated my post with some images, sorry for my english..

Comment: I think i found my solution here  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58976/views-to-display-nodes-based-on-acl-permission